# Disable/Enable Hyperlink on runtime in WPF DevExpress Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink, devexpress

I am working with DevExpress Grid control. This is the structure of my Grid:

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grd_NoPartNumberLinesapprovedbutnotReceived" Height="600">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>                                                      
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="emo_number" Header="EMO" VisibleIndex="10" AllowEditing="False">
            <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Data.Hyperlink}" 
                                   Click="ClickonEmoHyperlink" 
                                   TargetName="_blank">

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.emo_number}" />
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView x:Name="vwNoPartNumberLinesapprovedbutnotReceived" AutoWidth="True" ShowGroupPanel="False" />    
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

**`Problem`**

Now I want to disable Hyperlink on run time based on some condition otherwise in rest of cases it will be enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly bind the `IsEnabled` property of the Hyperlink control to a property in your view model like rest of the properties.

```
<Hyperlink  NavigateUri="{Binding Data.Hyperlink}" 
Click="ClickonEmoHyperlink" TargetName="_blank">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.emo_number}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding Data.IsEnabled}"/>
</Hyperlink>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Represents a trigger that applies property values or performs actions when the bound data meets a specified condition.

Example:

```
<DataTemplate>            
    <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" Tag="True">
        <Hyperlink Name="MyHyperlink" Click="Hyperlink_Click">
            <TextBlock Text="TestText" />
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>        

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=MyTextBlock}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="MyHyperlink" Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=MyTextBlock}" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="MyHyperlink" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

If `Tag` of TextBlock will be *True*, then `Hyperlink` is enabled, otherwise it will be disabled.

Also, you can Binding the property in `DataTrigger`. Add some property, for example `HyperlinkIsEnabled` to your Data, and in the DataTrigger write this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HyperlinkIsEnabled}" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="MyHyperlink" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
```

To successfully updated your properties, your `Data` class must implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface.

Comment: @Sunny: What property?

Comment: Sorry i was saying about Tag.

Comment: @Sunny: you can Binding the property in DataTrigger, for example: add property `HyperlinkIsEnabled` to your Data, and in the DataTrigger write this: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Data.HyperlinkIsEnabled}" Value="True">`. Tag it's property for example. Do not forget to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for Data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but i am using @ramb00's solution.